# Evaluating $48^{322} \pmod{25}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How do I find $48^{322} \pmod{25}$?

Comment: The question is short, but warrants inclusion here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recall Euler's theorem: $a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod n$, where $\gcd(a,n)=1$. We hence have
$$48^{20} \equiv 1 \pmod{25}$$
Hence,
$$48^{322} \equiv \left(48^{20}\right)^{16} \cdot 48^2 \pmod{25} \equiv 48^2 \pmod{25} \equiv (-2)^2 \pmod{25} \equiv 4 \pmod{25}$$

Comment: Thank you, so if I make the replacement $48 \leadsto 40$ we can side-step this noting that $40=(5*8)$, for which any power greater than $2$ gives a number ending in $25$ times some other number, so it's zero.

Comment: @BarisaBarukh Yes.

Comment: Could you explain the second congruence in the last "$$"-nest?

Comment: @BarisaBarukh $322 = 20 \times 16 + 2$. Hence, $$48^{322} = 48^{20 \times 16+2} = \underbrace{(48^{20})^{16}}_{1\pmod{25}} \cdot 48^2$$

Answer (score 1):

mod $\,25\!:\ 48^{322}\! \equiv (-48)^{322}\!\equiv 2^{322}\! \equiv 2^2\!\cdot (2^{10})^{32} = 4\cdot 1024^{32}\equiv 4\,(-1)^{32}\! \equiv 4$

Answer (score 0):

Finding the $\phi(n)$ for $25$ was easy, but what it if the $n$ was arbitrarily large?

$$48 \equiv -2( \mod 25)$$

Playing around with $-2(\mod 25)$ so as to get $1$ or $-1(\mod 25)$.

We see that $1024 \equiv -1(\mod 25)$

$$((-2)^{10})^{32} \equiv 1 (\mod 25)$$

$$(-2)^{322} \equiv  4(\mod 25)$$